# ActionListener Expression value for RichButton in ADF

Tags: action, actionlistener, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

We have a business need to collect specific bindings in every JSF page. and we do that inside overridden ViewHandlerWrapper class

I use the below code inside renderView method to get the whole expression value property for every RichInputText and it's work fine for me

```
ValueExpression valExp = Inputcomponent.getValueExpression("value");
String ExpressionString = valExp.getExpressionString();
```

output was: #{binding.EmployeeId.inputValue}

When I do the same against RichButtin I got null value as following:

```
ValueExpression valExp = Btncomponent.getValueExpression("actionlistener");
String ExpressionString = valExp.getExpressionString();
```

What is the wrong in my last peace of code?

Answer (score 0):

Obtaining a *ValueExpression* form a RichInputText works because, as the name suggests, it *evaluates* to a value, which may or may not be an EL expression, let alone a method.

On the other hand, a RichButton does not really have to evaluate to something; rather, it aims to invoke behavior (i.e. a method), from which you would want a *MethodExpression* - though in this case, the closest we get to it is a *MethodBinding*.

Luckily, UIXCommand, a superclass of RichButton, provides two methods from which you can obtain your action listeners:

1. `public final MethodBinding getActionListener()`

   From the MethodBinding returned, you can invoke `getExpressionString()`    so you can get what you wanted - such as some actionListener EL string like `#{binding.bean.actionListenerMethod}`.
2. `public final ActionListener[] getActionListeners()`

   Might be worth mentioning, though there is not much merit for this in your use case. It simply returns the listeners on which you can manually process the events.

Comment: It turns out that ADF does differentiate between a MethodBinding and a MethodExpression, though currently I am unsure as to the criteria for deciding between them.

Comment: Could you please provide me a clear lines of code. As I tried the above two solutions and it was return null also.

Comment: Oh, `String expString = Btncomponent.getActionListener().getExpressionString()` still returned null?

Comment: When does your renderView  method get called? Is it from an event of the page? What was the lifecycle phase when it was called?

(you can get the current lifecycle phase by printing out `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getCurrentPhaseId()`)

Comment: I will give it a try again and feedback you

Comment: the same result java.lang.NullPointerException